# Delete multiple emails from INBOX in gmail using GMAIL API

Tags: email, gmail

Is there a way to select multiple emails from INBOX in gmail using GMAIL API and delete them in one request. For ex: I have selected 3 mails to delete and delete them in only one request.

In GMAIL API i found  this
`service.users().threads().delete(userId, threadId).execute();`  in which i have to pass message id of mails one by one to delete which will consume a lot of time. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail provides API to delete multiple emails at once where you can pass multiple ids in request body. Here is the API reference.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/batchDelete

**Edit: Added Sample Ruby Code**

I used [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) v0.8.2 gem to make API calls. Here is a sample code.

```
require 'google/api_client'
@client = Google::APIClient.new({application_name: 'MyApp', application_version: 'MyAppVersion'})
@client.authorization.access_token = MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
@service = @client.discovered_api('gmail')

payload = {ids: ['id_1', 'id_2']} # You can add multiple ids here
result = @client.execute(
    :api_method => @service.users.messages.batch_delete,
    :parameters => {userId: 'me'},
    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
    :body => payload.to_json
)
puts result.success? # true/false
```

> **NOTE:** The API used in sample code will not move your messages to trash, rather it will permanently delete your messages.

Comment: What was the exact code you used? I always receive invalid IDs error

Comment: Update: I'm not sure I wrote the right code this time, but now I receive BackendError. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add the sample code for better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I like @Sambit answer but for people who use python religiously its service.users().message().batch Delete(userId=userid).body(jsonIds i.e. {'ids':'id', 'id', 'id'}) took me awhile to figure out, I hope I save someone's time